# Android MapView direction arrows

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, android-maps

I want to add direction arrows to my application to make it looks like [this](http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/088/Purple/fe/8d/ba/mzl.fjhutrbc.320x480-75.jpg). Is there any solutions or advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.*;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;
import com.google.android.maps.Projection;
import com.jettaxi.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrowDirectionsOverlay extends Overlay {
    private Context context;

    private ArrayList<GeoPoint> directions;
    private Bitmap arrowBitmap;
    private int maximalPositionX;
    private int maximalPositionY;

    public ArrowDirectionsOverlay(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        directions = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();

        arrowBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.direction);
    }

    public void addDirectionPoint(GeoPoint destination) {
        directions.add(destination);
    }

    public void clear() {
        directions.clear();
    }

    private double getAngle(GeoPoint center, GeoPoint destination) {
        double lat1 = center.getLatitudeE6() / 1000000.;
        double lon1 = center.getLongitudeE6() / 1000000.;
        double lat2 = destination.getLatitudeE6() / 1000000.;
        double lon2 = destination.getLongitudeE6() / 1000000.;

        int MAXITERS = 20;
        // Convert lat/long to radians
        lat1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
        lat2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
        lon1 *= Math.PI / 180.0;
        lon2 *= Math.PI / 180.0;

        double a = 6378137.0; // WGS84 major axis
        double b = 6356752.3142; // WGS84 semi-major axis
        double f = (a - b) / a;
        double aSqMinusBSqOverBSq = (a * a - b * b) / (b * b);

        double L = lon2 - lon1;
        double A = 0.0;
        double U1 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat1));
        double U2 = Math.atan((1.0 - f) * Math.tan(lat2));

        double cosU1 = Math.cos(U1);
        double cosU2 = Math.cos(U2);
        double sinU1 = Math.sin(U1);
        double sinU2 = Math.sin(U2);
        double cosU1cosU2 = cosU1 * cosU2;
        double sinU1sinU2 = sinU1 * sinU2;

        double sigma = 0.0;
        double deltaSigma = 0.0;
        double cosSqAlpha = 0.0;
        double cos2SM = 0.0;
        double cosSigma = 0.0;
        double sinSigma = 0.0;
        double cosLambda = 0.0;
        double sinLambda = 0.0;

        double lambda = L; // initial guess
        for (int iter = 0; iter < MAXITERS; iter++) {
            double lambdaOrig = lambda;
            cosLambda = Math.cos(lambda);
            sinLambda = Math.sin(lambda);
            double t1 = cosU2 * sinLambda;
            double t2 = cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda;
            double sinSqSigma = t1 * t1 + t2 * t2; // (14)
            sinSigma = Math.sqrt(sinSqSigma);
            cosSigma = sinU1sinU2 + cosU1cosU2 * cosLambda; // (15)
            sigma = Math.atan2(sinSigma, cosSigma); // (16)
            double sinAlpha = (sinSigma == 0) ? 0.0 :
                    cosU1cosU2 * sinLambda / sinSigma; // (17)
            cosSqAlpha = 1.0 - sinAlpha * sinAlpha;
            cos2SM = (cosSqAlpha == 0) ? 0.0 :
                    cosSigma - 2.0 * sinU1sinU2 / cosSqAlpha; // (18)

            double uSquared = cosSqAlpha * aSqMinusBSqOverBSq; // defn
            A = 1 + (uSquared / 16384.0) * // (3)
                    (4096.0 + uSquared *
                            (-768 + uSquared * (320.0 - 175.0 * uSquared)));
            double B = (uSquared / 1024.0) * // (4)
                    (256.0 + uSquared *
                            (-128.0 + uSquared * (74.0 - 47.0 * uSquared)));
            double C = (f / 16.0) *
                    cosSqAlpha *
                    (4.0 + f * (4.0 - 3.0 * cosSqAlpha)); // (10)
            double cos2SMSq = cos2SM * cos2SM;
            deltaSigma = B * sinSigma * // (6)
                    (cos2SM + (B / 4.0) *
                            (cosSigma * (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SMSq) -
                                    (B / 6.0) * cos2SM *
                                            (-3.0 + 4.0 * sinSigma * sinSigma) *
                                            (-3.0 + 4.0 * cos2SMSq)));

            lambda = L +
                    (1.0 - C) * f * sinAlpha *
                            (sigma + C * sinSigma *
                                    (cos2SM + C * cosSigma *
                                            (-1.0 + 2.0 * cos2SM * cos2SM))); // (11)

            double delta = (lambda - lambdaOrig) / lambda;
            if (Math.abs(delta) < 1.0e-12) {
                break;
            }
        }

        float distance = (float) (b * A * (sigma - deltaSigma));
        float initialBearing = (float) Math.atan2(cosU2 * sinLambda,
                cosU1 * sinU2 - sinU1 * cosU2 * cosLambda);
        initialBearing *= 180.0 / Math.PI;
        float finalBearing = (float) Math.atan2(cosU1 * sinLambda,
                -sinU1 * cosU2 + cosU1 * sinU2 * cosLambda);
        finalBearing *= 180.0 / Math.PI;

        return finalBearing;
    }

    private void drawArrow(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, GeoPoint destination) {
        Point screenPts = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(destination, null);

        int deltaX = mapView.getMapCenter().getLatitudeE6() - destination.getLatitudeE6();
        int deltaY = mapView.getMapCenter().getLongitudeE6() - destination.getLongitudeE6();

        double angle = getAngle(mapView.getMapCenter(), destination);
        double tan = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(angle));

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate((float) angle);
        Bitmap rotatedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                arrowBitmap,
                0, 0,
                arrowBitmap.getWidth(),
                arrowBitmap.getHeight(),
                matrix,
                true
        );

        int currentPositionX = screenPts.x - (rotatedBmp.getWidth() / 2);
        int currentPositionY = screenPts.y - (rotatedBmp.getHeight() / 2);

        if ((currentPositionX < 0) || (currentPositionY < 0) ||
                (currentPositionX > maximalPositionX) || (currentPositionY > maximalPositionY)) {

            int arrowPositionX = (int) (mapView.getWidth() / 2 - Math.signum(deltaX) * mapView.getHeight() / 2 * tan);
            arrowPositionX = Math.min(Math.max(arrowPositionX, 0), maximalPositionX);
            int arrowSpanX = (int) (mapView.getWidth() / 2.);

            int arrowPositionY = (int) (mapView.getHeight() / 2 + Math.signum(deltaY) * arrowSpanX / tan);
            arrowPositionY = Math.min(Math.max(arrowPositionY, 0), maximalPositionY);

            canvas.drawBitmap(
                    rotatedBmp,
                    arrowPositionX,
                    arrowPositionY,
                    null
            );
        }
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

        maximalPositionX = mapView.getWidth() - arrowBitmap.getWidth();
        maximalPositionY = mapView.getHeight() - arrowBitmap.getHeight();

        for (GeoPoint geoPoint : directions) {
            drawArrow(canvas, mapView, geoPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

Bitmap arrow points top in my case

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be to do a search for the places of interest (in this case coffee shops) which are within a certain distance from the users current location. This distance could be a 'screen' north, south, east or west of your current location - the screen distance will depend on your zoom level. The shops which are not on the current screen would then be represented by an arrow placed on the screen edge with the direction set between your current location and the shop.

Comment: I'm interested with arrows on screen edges. Can you provide your overlay example?

Comment: I've done several things with Maps but not this, so I don't have an example. It looks like the arrows are placed from the midpoint going left or right.

Comment: Can you describe algorithm of arrows positioning in pseudocode?